# get black screen after popScene

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I just started learning Cocos2dx, and use the basic HelloWorld project. I added a SecondScene and and a button in it to change scene. But once the popScene method executed, screen became black and it didn't pop to first scene. I don't have any idea what's wrong.
Here's the code I modified a little in HelloWorld.cpp:

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pushScene(SecondScence::scene());
#endif
```

Code in SecondScene:

```
#include "SecondScence.h"
USING_NS_CC;

CCScene* SecondScence::scene(){
CCScene* scene=CCScene::create();
SecondScence* layer = SecondScence::create();
scene->addChild(layer);
return scene;


bool SecondScence::init(){
CCLabelTTF* label = CCLabelTTF::create("hfiejfeiojfoej", "Arial", 30);
label->setPosition(ccp(200,200));
this->addChild(label);

CCMenuItemImage *pCloseItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
"CloseNormal.png","CloseSelected.png",this,menu_selector(SecondScence::popScene));
pCloseItem->setPosition(ccp(CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width-20, 20));

CCMenu *pMenu = CCMenu::create(pCloseItem,NULL);
pMenu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
this->addChild(pMenu,1);

return true;
}

void SecondScence::popScene(CCObject* pSender){
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->popScene();   
}
```

By the way, I use cocos2dx 2.2 and xcode5, the the console print a message:Cocos2d: cocos2d: deallocing CCDirector 0x6906f0

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the popScene method isn't run twice, perhaps by the user quickly tapping the menu item (or a bug).

That would pop both the current and the HelloWorld scene, leaving the director with no scene to display. It would also explain the director deallocating.

You can prevent this by first checking whether the director's `runningScene` is identical to `this` (as in: the SecondScene instance), and only then call popScene.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too, but I solved,
I think you may have removed all children from the scene,
check you onExit or destructor to see if any release/remove options available in these two functions.

if the scene has no children, it would be black.

Comment: the scene means the scene you push into stack.(pushScene())